# Issue in running cron jobs in RHEL5

Tags: linux, crontab, redhat-enterprise-linux, rhel-5, cronjob

When I try to run cron jobs from root, I am getting the following error. I am using RHEL5. Can anyone help me?

```
    [root@localhost]# crontab -e
    Permission denied
You (root) are not allowed to access to (crontab) because of pam configuration.
```

The contents of /etc/pam.d/crond is given below

```
#
# The PAM configuration file for the cron daemon
#
#
auth       sufficient pam_env.so
auth       required   pam_rootok.so
auth       include    system-auth
account    required   pam_access.so
account    include    system-auth
session    required   pam_loginuid.so
session    include    system-auth
```

Comment: Can you share the contents of /etc/pam.d/crond with us?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange.

Comment: I had same problem on Centos 7. No idea why, changing root's password with `passwd` solved my problem (it probably updated some permissions related settings).